# Which sentence is grammatically correct : I started the day with the thing that woke me up or I started the day with the thing that had woken me up

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Another related question : Is it okay to use past perfect tense in general past sentence like ,
I usually started a day with the thing that had woken me up.

Comment: Both sentences are extremely unlikely Siddharth.  Please give us more idiomatic examples and tell us which you think is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**One thing preceding another in the past.**

I usually **started** the day [at some point in the past] with the alarm [thing] that **had woken me** up.

Yes, that's grammatical.

In other words, in the past, you started your day and some thing had woken you up before you started your day.

What woke you up began before you started your day: the principle rule for using the past perfect.

**A plain statement of fact without reference to which came first**:

I usually started the day [at some point in the past] with the alarm [thing] that woke me up.

That is also grammatical.

The question here is: What do you as speaker **want to say**?

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean "thing that woke me up."

Consider the sentence:

> I started today when my alarm clock *woke* me up.

In this sentence, the past tense refers to a particular moment in time. The alarm clock made a noise, and you woke up.

Now consider this example:

> I started today by discovering that my alarm clock, which *had woken* me up every day for years, was no longer working.

The meaning here is different. The past perfect tense refers to a duration of time that happened earlier than the point in time you are talking about. It also often implies that something has changed since that time, and it is no longer the case. (Here, the alarm clock no longer works.)